# How do multiple web-workers communicate with each other?

Tags: javascript, multithreading, web-worker

I currently have two web workers. One, deals with physics, and the other rendering. They are started in a separate script, within an html document. How can the workers communicate with each other? Would I need to post a message from the main thread containing a transferable worker object identifying the workers?

TL:DR;

How can Worker A post messages to Worker B if Worker B is not defined within Worker A but rather elsewhere?